# If Exist or Exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, exists

Is it possible to test two `EXISTS` conditions in a single `IF` SQL statement?  I've tried the following.

```
IF EXIST (SELECT * FROM tblOne WHERE field1 = @parm1 AND field2 = @parm2) 
   OR 
   EXIST (SELECT * FROM tblTwo WHERE field1 = @parm5 AND field2 = @parm3)
```

I've tried playing with adding additional `IF` and parenthesis in there, but to no avail.

Can you help me out with the proper syntax?

Comment: @user1142433 - can you post your full query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If SQL Server

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   tblOne
           WHERE  field1 = @parm1
                  AND field2 = @parm2)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   tblTwo
               WHERE  field1 = @parm5
                      AND field2 = @parm3)
  PRINT 'YES'
```

Is fine, note the only thing changed is `EXISTS` not `EXIST`. The plan for this will probably be a `UNION ALL` that short circuits if the first one tested is true.

Comment: I'm getting "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'IF'." with that code.

Comment: @user1142433 - Please post the exact code you are using. The code in this answer doesn't give that error. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28328f/3)

Comment: Apologies.  Your solution works perfectly. I had an additional error in my sproc.

Answer (score 5):

You missed an S at the end of EXIST

EXIST**S**, not EXIST

Answer (score -1):

You could also write an IN statement

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblOne WHERE field1 = @parm1 AND field2 IN (@parm2,@parm3)
```

Comment: This is not useful for this question since the question addresses an IF EXISTS statement between two different tables (note tblOne and tblTwo in the code snippet provided).